# Admob Violation Message Android Application

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I received this message, but I don't understand what's wrong with my app,
can you help, please?

> As a courtesy, we are alerting you that your app is currently in
>   violation of the AdMob program policies. Importantly, this will
>   require action on your part to ensure no disruption in ad serving.
>   Please read below for more information on the actions you need to
>   take:
>
> Publisher Id:
>
> App Id:
>
> Current ad serving status: Active
>
> Violation explanation
>
> Publishers are not permitted to alter the behavior of AdMob ads in any
>   way. This includes resizing ad frames to cut off parts of ads or
>   hiding the Ads by AdMob moniker.
>
> Action required: Please make changes immediately to your app to comply
>   with AdMob program policies.
>
> Current account status: Active

Sometimes ads show on the app like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyWCE.png) and then it corrects itself.
What can be wrong in my code how can I correct it?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView> 

    <org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/xmllayoutexample_rendersurfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be sufficient to add `android:layout_below="@+id/adView"` into your `org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView`